# Good books on Discrete Math for CS?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, book-recommendation

I was looking for an exercise book on Discrete Math like SAT questions.
In particular I want questions on

1. Logic
2. Set Theroy
3. Relations (I.e., $R\subset A\times A$)
4. Functions
5. Combinatorics

I did not find anything like SAT questions but only "open" questions.

Comment: Check out Discrete Maths An Open Introduction by Oscar Levin. I enjoyed it